# sed not found but already installed

Tags: 13.04, sed

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. I'm trying to install ptxdist-2011.11.0 and when I run `./configure`, it says it doesn't find a sed version:

```
    checking sed version... configure: error: we need at least GNU sed 4.x
```

But when I run

```
sudo apt-get install sed
```

...it's already installed (`sed is already the newest version`).

I've checked the version and it's 4.2.2.

Could anyone tell me what to do? I can't change the ptxdist version.

Comment: I wonder if `sed` is not in your `$PATH`? Can you run `sed --version`? (Is that how you checked version?)

Comment: Yes, I ran sed --version. I've already checked the executable is in /bin

Comment: Could you post the exact output of the `configure` as you run it ?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get an answer. But please note that [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened. (Plus, new questions about 13.04 and other EoL releases [are off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8188/22949).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `ptxdist` [mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.embedded.ptxdist.devel/11074)

```
The check for the sed fails for newer sed versions have a different version
string. This was fixed in ptxdist-2013.01.0. If you need to use older
versions, then you need to backport the relveant fix (git commit
"2a89985 configure.ac: change regex for sed version")
```

So I recommend using  the latest version or modifying the file `configure.ac` according to the git commit `2a89985`.

`git log -p 2a89985` will show you the changes in that commit

You can clone `ptxdist` using

```
git clone git://git.pengutronix.de/git/ptxdist.git
```

change current working directory into the ptxdist repository

`cd ptxdist`

checkout your bsp ptxdist version

`git checkout ptxdist-2012.03.0`

grab the fix commit

`git cherry-pick 2a89985`

generate autotools files for the buildsystem, you will need that because the git directory doesn't contains these files.

`./autogen.sh`

install ptxdist in the usual way (`./.configure ... && make && make install`)

There should be now a new ptxdist binary in your $PATH on correct install path. Migrate the bsp for that (That's okay because we know there was only one change and this is the bugfix for the buildsystem and doesn't change anything in ptxdist).

[source](https://www.mail-archive.com/ptxdist@pengutronix.de/msg08097.html)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is the git commit 2a899985 and how can I get it, so I can make the changes I need.

Comment: @Trouble-lling Here is a complete guide on how to do it https://www.mail-archive.com/ptxdist@pengutronix.de/msg08097.html

Answer (score 0):

When you're compiling something that is dependent on sed you need the sed development package installed. Usually the development package is named after the actual package with "-dev" appended.  Try:

apt-get install sed-dev